# wrong developer name iphone app store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

The developer name that appears below the app name and on the nav bar when we go to developer info is not the same as the name in my developer profile. I have double checked both my profile and the code but I cannot find where the app is getting the wrong developer name. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Is this showing the name of person whose credit you used ?

Comment: i didn't understand your question, please add some description. if possible add code snippets.

Comment: no. that name is not in my app or anywhere in the developer profile. nor in the credit card.

Comment: so may i know do you know the name of there is some kind of unknown name ?

Comment: the name is not unknown. I had to upload the app as a new app since I had to change the name. I had deleted the old version. But I think this has something to do with that.

Comment: If the name is not unknown, it must come from somewhere. Is it your creditcard/billing name, personal name or developer profile name?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you're going to have to contact Apple directly.

[Here is the link to reach out to them](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).

There's no easy or official way to change your name in the App Store. When you first list an app for the first time on the app store there's a screen where you can type in your (or your company) name for display within the store and it says in big bold letters some language like ["This can not be changed later on"](http://happipapi.com/blog/choose-your-app-store-name-wisely-it-cannot-be-changed).

So if you want this changed, and if you're lucky and patient, somebody on the Apple side will have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes connect helpdesk is great and answer quickly and could give you some tips (and even call you back).
Just a question, you entered also a company name, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
wrong developer name iphone app store
```

Please [contact us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) for assistance with:

- Address changes
- Contact information updates
- Company/Organization name updates or changes

or there is [link for FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/) and Good link for [Account Management.](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html)

But as i faced a problem related to this I don't had my credit card, so i used one of my relative's card then under Seller name it showed the name from the credit card. then i did  contact in iTunes Connect to request for changing the name change and its applied within a few days.so this may a reason for you or related.

Comment: @user2160539 please review